# redeclaration of variable with no linkage

Tags: c

I hav tis example code here which i am trying.

```
char test[256], test1[256];

char *combine =("Hello '%s', '%s'",test,test2);
```

how can I parse the value of my test test1  into my char *combine? I get an error of redeclaration of no linkage for my test and test1.

Comment: This isn't C. Perhaps you are inspired by python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). It will allow you to combine the two strings.

So, something like:

```
char combine[LARGE_ENOUGH_NUMBER_HERE]
sprintf(combine, "Hello %s %s", test1, test2);
```

Comment: Thanks Alot. That was what i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
char *combine = ("Hello '%s', '%s'", test, test2);
```

doesn't look like C at all. If you want to write into a formatted string, you should rather use `sprintf` family (from the standard header `<stdio.h>`). You can check the documentation throughout the Web. If you use C99, it is a better idea to use `snprintf`, which is much more secured.

```
// C99

#include <stdio.h>

char combine[1024]; /* Should be long enough to hold the string. */
snprintf (combine, sizeof combine, "Hello '%s', '%s'", test, test2);
```